# Recharts not display negative values on LineBarAreaComposedChart React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I'm trying to optimize the graph with 6 variable values.

Sometimes some of these values are negative, and the graph does not show them.

I tried to put negative values on the Y scale, but that's not working either.

The Line itself on the graph disappears.

The wind speed line has positive values but it is not visible either.

[image: LineBarAreaComposedChart]

My code:

```
<div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <ComposedChart width={1100} height={800} data={this.state.data} stackOffset="sign">
              <XAxis dataKey="Date" />
              <YAxis />
              <Tooltip />
              <Legend />
              <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
              <Area type='monotone' dataKey='Apress' fill='#726a64' stroke='#726a64' />
              <Bar dataKey='Rain' barSize={20} fill='#000cff'>
                <LabelList dataKey="Rain" position="top" />
              </Bar>
              <Bar dataKey='Snow' barSize={20} fill='#6387ff'>
                <LabelList dataKey="Snow" position="top" />
              </Bar>
              <Line type='monotone' dataKey='Temp' stroke='#ff0000' />
              <Line type='monotone' dataKey='WindSpeed' stroke='#00ff1a' />
            </ComposedChart>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add props `stackOffset=“sign”` to `BarChart`.

The default value is none which is why you don’t get negative values.